# Tried to send a platform message response, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Response ID: 4

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'am creating an application which send the users current location periodically to server. So if the app is in background it should also need to work. I'am using workmanager plugin to work the app in background. But i'am getting this error when the app is in background.
`Tried to send a platform message response, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Response ID: 4.`